# Pure -Vs injection or must it be together with Vs?

Tags: operational-amplifier

My Op-Amp needs to be supplied with -Vs to increase the negative rail swing. Can I just add a negative power supply directly to the -Vs with the existing 5V +Vs retained. If yes. Where do I connect the ground of the independent -Vs power supply? Can its ground just float?

If the -Vs can't be injected independently, why?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I just add a negative power supply directly to the -Vs with the existing 5V +Vs retained?

Yes, as long as your op-amp can withstand a supply voltage of  10 V across its supply pins during operation, as indicated by its datasheet.

> If yes. Where do I connect the ground of the independent -Vs power supply? Can its ground just float?

Its ground should be the same ground as the positive supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN0VG4m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> If the -Vs can't be injected independently, why?

If you let the negative supply float, it's not actually applying -5V relative to the ground that you're already using for your op amp and your signals. Furthermore, the op amp needs some supply current to bias and power its internal circutiry, and with this broken open loop, no current can flow via the supply rails.

Depending on the type of op amp, supply current may or may not flow out through the input/output pins during such a scenario, but by that point the op amp is simply malfunctioning.

[image: schematic]

If you cannot find a separate supply with independent ground, you may choose to use a charge pump or other circuit to generate the negative rail. Alternatively, you may choose to use a +10V supply, and instead bias the input and output *signals* at +5V so they're midway between the rails.

Comment: Its for the AD620 op amp. But why cant I find any power supply that can supply -5 volts independently? Doesn't any company make this at all? Is it too hard to make?

Comment: @Jtl Plenty of companies produce power supplies that can make a negative rail. In fact, if you read my answer carefully, the second to last sentence gives a specific such power supply - a negative voltage charge pump. There are plenty of commercially-available charge pump ICs that provide this exact functionality. If you are having trouble finding such a supply. chances are you may have been using the wrong keywords or parameters.

Comment: @Jtl Also be mindful - while the AD620 can handle your desired range, it is ***not*** an op-amp. It's an instrumentation amplifier.